# When i tried to send a part of Json body from the csv file in the request getting **ERR**

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

Issue : When i tried to send a part of Json body from the csv file in the request getting **ERR** . I know  as per the reference document it throws **ERR** when uable to open the csv file Or spaces.

Not sure what went wrong.

Below are the screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check what's in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Normally you cannot use [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as the CSV file path in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), as per JMeter Test Elements [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) the CSV Data Set Config is being executed **before anything else** so the variable might not be yet initialized.

If this is the case - consider using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead, check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for more details.

If this is not the case - check both variables values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and the presence of the file under the path where `${dealmemodetails}` variable is pointing.